# Flutter : How to Map values dynmically into list and iterate to its length and how can i do Update and Delete after maping values

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build json expected output as below through dart programing for my application, I have mapped data to list successfully. But when I trying to delete / add the list, the elements in the list are not getting updated accordingly instead they are hgetting reapeted same data.

Here is my code implimentation

in this set state i am getting required values like Phone, name, email e.t.c

```
for (int i = 0; i <= selectedContacts.length - 1; i++) {
        SimplifiedContact? contact = selectedContacts.elementAt(i);

        CreateContestModel(//<-- from here i am getting required values.
          contact.phone, 
          contact.name,
          contact.email,
        );
      }
```

in below code i am, mapping data and building json

```
class CreateContestModel {

  static List models = [];

  String phone = '';
  String name = '';
  String email;

   CreateContestModel(this.phone, this.name, this.email) {
      var invitemap = {
      'name': name,
      'phone': phone,
      'email': email,
    };

    models.add(invitemap);
    print(models);
   }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

```
{
   "invitations":[
      {
         "name":"Acevedo Castro",
         "phone":982-475-2009,
         "email":"floresjoyner@digifad.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Acevedo Castro",
         "phone":982-475-2009,
         "email":"floresjoyner@digifad.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Abby Webster",
         "phone":888-561-2141,
         "email":"howardnoel@perkle.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Abby Webster",
         "phone":888-561-2141,
         "email":"howardnoel@perkle.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Abby Webster",
         "phone":888-561-2141,
         "email":"howardnoel@perkle.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you see above items are not getting updated, but they are getting added more.

**Expected Output**

```
{
   "invitations":[
      {
         "name":"Acevedo Castro",
         "phone":"982-475-2009",
         "email":"floresjoyner@digifad.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Abby Webster",
         "phone":"888-561-2141",
         "email":"howardnoel@perkle.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is some seriously flawed program flow. Your object creation as a side effect at the same time fills a static list. And it seems you call your object creation *every build*. So you would insert into your list whenver the user flips it's phone or drags his browser window.

I'm not entirely sure what you *want*, but you need state management in your application. There are different ways to do it, you can pick the one you like best from [the Flutter documentation on state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Comment: I have followed this code and migrate to null safety https://github.com/28harishkumar/flutter_contact_list

Comment: Do you understand, why when you tilt your phone or resize your browser window, the list gets longer and longer and longer? Set a breakpoint and watch how it gets hit every time the build function is called.

Comment: Sure Thanks, once i done that i will update question

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge flow issue, You should never do data manipulation in `build()` function as in flutter build function is called multiple times so the manipulation code will also get called multiple times.

So, the proper way to manipulate data is before the data is being used so make sure that the data is only manipulated in `initstate()`. In Your case you are also doing something which is not required. You are trying to add data to a list via a constructor to a static list so it will always add the data whenever you call it, This is not a proper way.

```
class CreateContestModel {
  late String phone = '';
  late String name = '';
  late String email;

  CreateContestModel.fromMap(Map<String, String> json) {
    phone = json['phone'] ?? '';
    phone = json['name'] ?? '';
    phone = json['email'] ?? '';
  }
}
```

This is how you should create your class. And always create functions for manipulation if possible.

```
  List<CreateContestModel> createContestModelList =
      testData['invitations']!.map(
    (data) {
      return CreateContestModel.fromMap(data);
    },
  ).toList();
```

Then use this code to construct your list in `initstate()` and manipulate this having a static variable in your stateful widget. Make Sure you do not construct the data on `build()` function.

Need More Help?? here's the [Gist link](https://gist.github.com/RitickSaha/d2b5e66843ae6c3f3770632e8d43ed2f)

Answer (score 0):

As per my question i find some work around, i.e., by clear up stack on selecting or updtaing existing contacts because as explained below

in this for loop i am itrating same values on each time, when i hit on submit button

```
for (int i = 0; i <= selectedContacts.length - 1; i++) { //<--- for every time same elements will be itrated
        SimplifiedContact? contact = selectedContacts.elementAt(i);

        CreateContestModel(//<-- from here i am getting required values.
          contact.phone, 
          contact.name,
          contact.email,
        );
      }
```

so the list of sets are not updating as per the displayed list as mentioned in question, so i done some work around in below code while selecting / updating contacts, because my model is static list

```
void onContactBtnPress(BuildContext context) async { CreateContestModel.models.clear(); //<-- clearing up stack
}
```